# Google Insights Pagespeed response read in java

Tags: java, google-api, google-pagespeed

I tried my hard to try to read results from google insights pagespeed api, which response in json format. But didnt get what to read and how ie how to present my result to my UI and the hard is the code to read that json file to read in java

Comment: What have you tried? What is not working as expected?

Comment: The way the Google insight website presents its data, I dont know properly how to read the response of Insights API and how to present it.